# Linux network monitor with web interface

Tags: linux, web-apps, gratis, network-monitor

I am looking for a free web-based network monitor for CentOS. It should contain at least:

- Bandwidth monitor
- Server health
- Load average
- Disk usage

Which one do you recommend?

**Note**: "Web-based" meaning that can be accessed from the a web browser interface (even if the actual monitoring takes place locally on the CentOS machine).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/)** is the monitoring tool of my choice (though I'm running Debian and Ubuntu on my machines; *Monitorix* is available for many distributions, including RedHat/Fedora/CentOS). It of course includes network traffic...

[image: Network traffic] [image: Network port traffic]
<sup>Network traffic: overall and per port (click images for original size)</sup>

...but also much more system health criteria, even details for several network applications (web servers/caches, bind, MySQL, etc.). Naturally, disk usage, load, and overall health state are included as well. Saved my day more than once. Checkout the [screenshot page](http://www.monitorix.org/screenshots.html) for more details.

[image: system load] [image: file systems]
<sup>system load and file-system usage</sup>

*Monitorix* is light-weight, includes its own web service (by default, listening on port 8080) which can be protected with username/passwort (HTTP Auth), and is well maintained (disclosure: I'm its maintainer for Debian/Ubuntu packages and the corresponding repository). 24/7 you find the dev himself and several of us maintainers on its IRC channel if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

I use **[Netdata](https://my-netdata.io/)** and I would highly recommend it. It's easy to install, light-weight, and provides real-time monitoring for everything you listed, and much more. I am running it on a variety of Linux systems from single-board computers to servers. You can view a live demo **[here](http://newyork.my-netdata.io)**.

[image: Netdata, real-time web-based monitoring]

**[PyDash](https://gitlab.com/k3oni/pydash)** is worth checking out, too.

[image: PyDash, light-weight web-based monitoring written in Python]

Answer (score 0):

## [eZ Server Monitor](http://www.ezservermonitor.com/)

It is a lightweight open source Linux server monitoring solution consisting of two products:

- **eSM `Web** - a web aplication in PHP (no database needed!):

  [image: eSM Web]
- **eSM `SH** - a shell application:

  [image: eSM SH]

As an alternative you can use **[Mumin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)**, which is also lightweight and is based on Perl and RRDTool.