# Apache graphing tool for Linux (Centos 5)?

Tags: linux, monitoring, apache

Is there an easy to install Apache graphing tool for Linux? Something which requires minimal setup and configuration? I'm having problems with slow loading times on a LAMP application and would like to check how Apache is performing.

**Requirements**

- Must work on Centos 5.
- Minimal configuration needed.
- Should graph usage to help pinpoint problems like max connections exceeded, etc.

**Nice to haves**

- Create own logs rather than working from just Apache logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/)** might come in handy here. It does not exactly *focus* on Apache, but of course includes Apache-specific data:

[image: Monitorix: Apache statistics]
<sup>Monitorix: Apache Statistics (source: [Monitorix.Org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeJ7gm.png); click image for larger variant)</sup>

As the graph shows, you can easily see a "journal" of Apache resource usage: idle/busy workers, requests, CPU-usage. Together with plenty of other statistics (see [here](http://www.monitorix.org/screenshots.html) for more screenshots; there can be other reasons for your "slow loading times", e.g. another process hogging all resources), this gives a pretty good image on your server's performance. Statistics are saved using [RRDTool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool), and the web front-end allows you to select different intervals to view the stored data.

*Monitorix* is [available for download](http://www.monitorix.org/downloads.html) for multiple systems, and easily installed on most Linux distros directly via their package management ([APT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) on Debian and its derivates, [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) for RedHat/Mandriva/SuSE etc). For more details, please also see my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/469/185).

I'm using *Monitorix* on multiple servers, and it saved my day more than once. The dev is quite busy implementing new features, and support is great also on its IRC channel in case you need help quickly.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer for the *Monitorix* Debian/Ubuntu packages and the corresponding [repository](http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu/dists/generic/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at how Apache is performing using system resources, or how apache is performing serving web pages? I am unfamiliar with Apache, but if errors like connections exceeded are logged in the Apache logs, perhaps something like Logstash sending to an ElasticSearch db, then viewed with the Kibana front end?

I've used this for Windows IIS logs, and I could graph things like http response codes, response times, bytes sent/received etc, all over a customiseable time.

There is some overhead setting up the grok filter within the logstash agent, but after you get that done, it just kind of works.

edit adding links -

logstash - http://www.logstash.net
elasticsearch and kibana - http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/

Comment: please include link - otherwise user may or may not find the right thing if they have to search.