# Linux program to monitor hardware sensors (temperatures, fans and voltages)?

Tags: linux, monitoring, hardware

I would like to find a good quality Linux program to **monitor the hardware sensors** of a computer. I would like the most of this features, if possible:

- Both command-line and GUI, or at least **command-line**.
- **Remote managing** (via network).
- **Logging** results to file.

I have tested **sensors** from *lm-sensors* Debian package:

```
fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:      124.92 W  (crit = 124.92 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +6.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +90.0°C, hyst = +87.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +37.0°C  

radeon-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +33.0°C  

radeon-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +37.0°C
```

but **AIDA64** (for Windows only) outperforms it:

[image]

Isn't there anything so valuable for **Linux**?

Comment: I use `sensors`. On a side note, I wonder if the sensors lose their calibration and that they are not re-calibrated. How much of an error would I have?

Answer (score 4):

Let me repeat a recommendation I already placed twice: **[Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/)**. It can be used as

- [Webbased Network analyzer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/468/185#469)
- [Apache graphing tool for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1955/185#1957)

But it also monitors "local resources" such as CPU, disks, and – sensors:

[image: Complete LM-Sensors and GPU temperatures] [image: Disk drive temperatures and health]
<sup>*Monitorix:* Complete LM-Sensors and GPU temperatures / Disk drive temperatures and health (source: [Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/); click to enlarge)</sup>

Monitorix makes use of a lot of back-ends, such as the already mentioned *lm-sensors* Debian package. It also supports *HP ProLiant System Health*, *NVIDIA temperatures and usage*, plus several more. I'm using it for quite a while now, and found the software that convincing I volunteered to maintain the Debian packages for it (← disclosure). *Monitorix* saved my day more than once, as its "raw overview" makes it pretty easy to track down problems and to see where to have a closer look at. In your case: find the graph with the highest peak to see which component is "overheating", for example.

*Monitorix* is a web-based tool, so you won't have that "interactive view" from the AIDA64 screenshot in your question. But AIDA64 might miss the graphs.

To your requested features:

- *Both command-line and GUI, or at least command-line:* *Monitorix* is a Perl program, which can be managed via command-line (start/stop, editing its plain-text config, etc.)
- *Remote managing (via network):* sure, simply get a command-line via the network (e.g. via SSH)
- *Logging results to file:* kind of. *Monitorix* uses [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rrdtool) for logging, so you'll have RRD files (Round-Robin-Database). But it also offers to send alerts, and more – so this might be "abused" to plug in some other logging, when needed.