# Software to monitor my hardware and graph the results

Tags: windows, monitoring, hardware

I want to find a piece of software that can:

- Monitor all the various types of computer hardware (e.g. CPU temp/clock/actives cores/voltage, GPU temp/clocks/utilization, HDD readwrite speeds/cache use, fan speeds);
- Have the option of producing real-time graphs for these values;
- Save and load these graphs (as data, not images);
- Change the graphs' time scale.
- Display all the graphs within a single window (but not necessarily on the same plane);
- Start after a reboot and display the graphs without user input;
- Start quickly and operate without consuming too much resources.

Currently I use tools like Intel Extreme Tuning Utility and NVIDIA Inspector to monitor separate components of the PC, but I'd like a one-stop solution for all components.

A couple of screenshots to demonstrate the sort of thing I'm interested in:

[image: Intel Extreme Tuning Utility]

[image: NVIDIA Inspector]

Comment: System Chronicle is working on something similar at its early stage. Might worth checking it out at: http://www.syschr.com

Answer (score 2):

Here are a list of software you should look. Please note that every software in the list will not be able to satisfy your needs.

- All of them are able to give details about all the hardware parts.
- Some of them provides facilities to produce real time graphs and save them.
- Almost every software in the list is light weight and don't consume much resources. Sandra Lite will be a contradiction to this.

List-

1. Sandra Lite (Free)
2. HWiNFO (Free)
3. HWMonitor (Free)
4. CPU-Z (Free)
5. AIDA64 Business Edition (Commercial Trial)
6. AIDA64 Extreme Edition (Commercial Trial)

Comment: Do any of these fit all of the requirements?

Comment: @kotekzot Sandra Lite and AIDA64 may fit all the requirements.

Comment: +1 for HWMonitor, really lightweight, easy to use and no installation required.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** found another option.

**1. AIDA64**

As per the similar question at [Linux program to monitor hardware sensors (temperatures, fans and voltages)?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2545/2742) you might find that AIDA64 http://www.aida64.com/ does what you need.

AIDA64 starts from $39.95 for home/personal use only and is probably much easier to install and set up than option 2 below.

**2. MRTG or RRD Tool**

Assuming that the devices being monitored are SNMP compatible and that you can install (or already have) PERL on your machine, then MRTG is a good free solution: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Here's the example from the home page:

[image]

MRTG can show daily, weekly, monthly and yearly graphs for each item that is being monitored.

**Edit:** There is also RRDTool from the same author: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/

**Edit:** As you have found, you need a different tool for each manufacturer but the nice thing about MRTG and RRDTool is that they are vendor agnostic and it doesn't matter who the manufacturer is as long as they have enabled SNMP for the device.

Comment: How do I use it to monitor something other than network traffic? Also, it doesn't seem to be real-time.

Comment: MRTG will monitor anything that supports SNMP, this can be anything from a weather station to fluid levels in a receptacle to the free space on the hard drive on your computer. As long as the device is SNMP compatible, you should be good to go. You might need an SNMP browser to help identify the relevant MIBs to monitor. I used to use Getif but you might need something more up to date. This might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/148741/looking-for-a-good-snmp-browser-to-run-under-windows

Comment: The graphs show historical data. You can make the polling as frequent as you like and set the graphs to automatically refresh. Would that work?

Comment: I don't think reloading a PNG every second or so would be a good experience. I'll give AIDA64 a go, thanks! Sorry about the delay, I was away.

Comment: Real time data is useful but historical data can often be more useful in identifying issues. Your CPU running at 70 degrees C is not especially useful information in isolation but if it was running at a steady 50 degrees C yesterday and last week and last year, then you know something has changed and may need investigating. This is probably obvious but I thought I'd point it out anyway! :)

Comment: That's true, I'll add a requirement to be able to change the graph's timescale.

Comment: AIDA64 seems really good at reading sensors, but not graphing the result; it seems I'd have to spend 60 minutes setting up a custom sensor panel, and 10 minutes more whenever I wanted to resize it. Is this right, or am I missing some option to display graphs for a bunch of sensors without manually adding and styling every single sensor's graph?