# What software or daemon did you use to monitor Linux systems/servers

Tags: linux, logs, network-monitor, monitoring, log-analysis

The monitored items are:

- historical SSH login/logout
- historical network upload and download bandwidth usage
- which network interfaces is down
- which server/system is down
- historical CPU usage
- historical RAM usage
- see logs (systemd) or `/var/log`

Comment: Except for the last item, I'd say *Monitorix* is a good choice. See my [answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2548/185) (and the ones I've linked from there). It's what I use – and if you're on Debian (or a derivate), I'm the maintainer of its `.deb` packages and the corresponding repository.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Nagios (http://www.nagios.org/) for some of your goals. I am a sysadmin and I use it on Fedora (only for basic tasks here, but I think it's versatile and useful).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We like our answers to be full fledged personal recommendations, rather then a link and "this could work". Could you tell us about your experiences with this tool? In doubt have a look at [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). Hope to see you around!