# Software to detect security problems in logs for NGINX or other Unix programs

Tags: security, unix, nginx

I see online recommendations that I look through logs in `/var/log` for attacks on my webserver, or security issues with the (Ubuntu Linux) system at large, but it would be helpful if I had something that could look for me and email me about anything suspicious.

I have seen some pages about log management software, but I'm not sure what would be effective, especially for someone who is not doing this as a business.  What are some good packages to look at?  Or does what I'm looking for exist?

Comment: Are you looking for a plain monitoring tool (like [Monitorix](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/linux-network-monitor-with-web-interface/469?s=3|0.3013#469)) – or rather something that takes action itself on defined patterns (like [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/))? Both can configured to send mails on defined events (in fact, I'm using both but not their mail feature ;)

Comment: `Fail2ban` looks like the thing. Thanks!  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a combination of [Monitorix](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/linux-network-monitor-with-web-interface/469?s=3|0.3013#469) (for long-term evaluation) and **[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/)** on my machines. Both can send out email alerts, though I'm not using that feature.

For your case, I'd especially recommend *Fail2Ban:*

- **look through logs in `/var/log`:** Exactly what it does. Already ships with a set of rules which you can extend by your own (using regular expressions).
- **email me about anything suspicious:** not only that, it can take immediate precautions – e.g. banning a given "attacker IP" for a specified amount of time (that's behind the name: "X failed logins → Ban!").

It's quite effective, and for me runs as kind of "automatic [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system)": bans hackers (web, mail, ssh and more) as well as "leechers", and a lot more. It knows about a bunch of often-used software and its log formats (e.g. Apache, OpenSSH, ProFTP, misc. mail servers), so even out-of-the-box you get something useful. Though most stuff (except for SSH) is "disabled" by default, it takes a few minutes to pick the ones you use and activate them.

Once you've got a bit familiar with it, you even start writing your own rules – and have it interact with other services (e.g. Apache's `mod_security`: let that throw some "EMERGENCY" type of events, and have Fail2Ban act on them). I can only warmly recommend it.

Comment: mod_security has a lot of false positives, and I had to comment out or modify many of the rules.

Comment: @cybernard So did I – but having adjusted it accordingly, it does a great job. `mod_security` was just mentioned as example here – the recommended software is Fail2Ban :)