# Open Source Monitoring Tool for Linux Server

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, monitoring

I want to know if there is a good, handy and especially open source Monitoring Tool for Linux Server. I only have SSH and HTTPS access to the server (I don't have a GUI or physical Access).

My requirements:

- Web Interface for the "Host" System which also can run on Smartphones
- Detailed list of Services of a specific server
- Event-Log capturing(it would be nice if it could easily filter the errors and warnings
- Monitoring of Network, Hardware and special Software(if its running) + Ports(if they are in use)
- Secured Access
- E-Mail alert over an external E-Mail Server

I use Debian 8 Wheezy.

Comment: *I found several Tools but no one could help me really out...* - which have you tested and why they couldn't help you out?

Comment: Oh ok i'm sorry that i haven't defined it right :D I'll edit asap... Yeah btw. I only know that i haven't tested mostly paid Monitoring Tools which would habe a paid license activation, i had so mich Problems with uninstalling it and searching for Open source Tools(i found too many) that i just want to Listen to some experienced users which could recommend one :)

Comment: Please see [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/469/185): **[Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/)** is what I use myself (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer for the `*.deb` packages of this tool). I'm running it on multiple machines, a.o. Ubuntu and Debian Wheezy (umm, and Debian 8 is Jessie IMHO – where *Monitorix* should work on as well ;) 64bit (Ubuntu, Wheezy) and ARM (Wheezy) in my case.

Comment: Hello @Izzy thanks for your recommendation, it looks not bad but I didn't see something about SMTP Support for getting Notifications if a Service is offline?

Comment: That wasn't asked for in the referenced question. There is a mail feature in *Monitorix,* though I must admit I never used that, just grep the [feature list page](http://www.monitorix.org/features.html) for "alert capabilities". But you're right, I don't see a "service down" or similar covered there. Feel free to check with [its Github presence](https://github.com/mikaku/Monitorix) and open an issue for it if you decide for Monitorix (or would do so if that feature were added), Jordi/mikaku always responds nicely to such things.

Comment: Yes it was :D The last entry in the list :P Ok I gonna look for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look at Zabbix (https://zabbix.org), a very powerful open source monitoring tool.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? And can it be installed using only SSH and HTTP?

Comment: You can see example screenshots at http://www.zabbix.com/screenshots.php

The 'usual' way to install Zabbix is via OS packages (i.e. using apt-get/aptitude/apt, yum, etc) so SSH access is enough (assuming you have root/sudo access). Installation instructions for recent RedHat and Debian based distributions are linked from the downloads page at http://www.zabbix.com/download.php.

Comment: It looks very nice and intuitive. I'll give it a try and install it on Saturday :) It seems that it provides every function i need.

Comment: Please, feel free to edit your answer after you read and incorporate the [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). You should have some experience using the software. What exactly did you like about it, and what did you not like as much? How does the software match each requirement in the question? Short answers get deleted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My organisation uses [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/downloads/), and at a glance it may well suit your needs. The Core version is free/OSS and it is well regarded in the industry.

It comes with various [web-based UI](https://www.nagios.org/downloads/nagios-core-frontends/)s, and can be installed manually, or you can download a ready-made VM, though your particular restrictions may preclude this.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? And can it be installed using only SSH and HTTP?

Comment: Nagios Core is not a bad option but it's has some negative aspects if you are want some functions of the pro version :( But i can recommend it :D It's just not the solution for my purposes.